# Simple git clone mangles many files with phantom, un-resettable 'modified' state (LF-related?) - how to fix local, remote, or in new clone?

Tags: git, github, line-endings, lf

Some recent change in a Github repository I use often (Python `gensim`) has created a problem evident even in fresh clones (to a Ubuntu system with git-2.17.1): immediately after the clone, nearly *all* of the files already show as 'modified', and even the normal 'git checkout -- ' can't reset this unwanted, effectively spurious state. (Thus it's impossible to do anything useful, even switching to an alt branch, in that working directory.)

Specifically, in a completely fresh directory, I run:

```
git clone https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim.git
```

It appears to succeed. However, a `git status` immediately shows many, many modified files:

```
$ cd gensim
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   docs/notebooks/index
[...
140+ other files
...]
    modified:   jupyter_home.png

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Trying something like `git checkout -- jupyter_home.png` has no effect: it still appears as modified.

Trying `git diff` print a bunch of the warnings of the following type, even for binary file types (like PNGs), before also showing alarming per-file diffs:

```
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in docs/notebooks/index.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

While I initially encountered this on Ubuntu, it's also reproducible to a lesser extent under MacOS. (Just 8 files, rather than 140+, arrive in mangled 'modified' state.)

I strongly suspect a [recent commit](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/commit/93385d331935fd8eeedb3f52b4dd8883dc86695c#diff-fc723d30b02a4cca7a534518111c1a66) that added a `.gitattributes` file with the following content:

```
% cat .gitattributes 
* text eol=lf
```

However, I have no idea how that alone would so mangle the working-directory, and removing it has no immediate effect on the state reported by `git status`.

I'd like to be able to make a fresh clone without this problem - but I'd also like to understand & fix any remote-side issues that triggered this new behavior, so that others can do a simple `clone` without problems, and there's no risk of mangling binary files with unintentional line-end edits.

How can I fix my clone, or do a fresh clone without this problem? Can the remote repo itself be fixed to prevent this from biting others who simply want a working clone without other local config changes?

(FWIW none of the `core.autocrlf` config options often suggested around similar issues, if set before the `clone`, changes the problem in any way – not `git config --global core.autocrlf true`, `git config --global core.autocrlf false`, nor `git config --global core.autocrlf input`.)

Comment: By adding `* text eol=lf` to `.gitattributes`, you are asking git to treat all files(including binary files like `*.png`) as text and filter the files by the changing their line endings to `LF`. Instead of doing this for all files, decide which files (based on filename or file type) should be treated as text by git and then add the same to `.gitattributes`, ex : `filename text eol=lf` or `*.file_type text eol=lf`

Comment: Thank you! Deleting the file in a branch at the repo, and checking out a branch without the file, yielded a usable working-directory.